# Factory Girl with enum and association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, enums, factory-bot

I have a model that uses both an association and an enum attribute.

```
class ProjectItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  enum status: {open: 0, pending: 1, completed: 2}
```

When I'm running a test on the create action of a model with an association, I use `build(:model_name).attributes` like this:

```
it "creates a new ProjectItem" do
  expect {
    post :create, document_project_item: build(:project_item).attributes
  }.to change(ProjectItem, :count).by(1)
end
```

This was failing, and I found [this issue thread that explains why it doesn't work](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/680). Based on the comment, I was able to determine that on tables with an `enum` attribute but no association, things work with `attributes_for(:model_name)` as expected.

The issue thread doesn't seem to suggest a work around, though I'll admit I don't understand what 100% of what the FactoryGirl methods are doing behind the scenes. Here's the factory:

```
factory :project_item do
  project
  name { Faker::Company.bs }
  description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
  status :open
  due { Faker::Date.between(2.days.ago, 10.days.from_now) }
  sequence(:position) {|n| n }
  completed_at { Faker::Date.between(1.year.ago, Date.today) }
end
```

I tried putting an integer in `status` as well, but I get the same error:

```
 Failure/Error: post :create, project_item: build(:project_item).attributes
 ArgumentError:
   '0' is not a valid status
```

Comment: Have you inspected the value of status within the response of attributes_for or build(something).attributes? Also, try using `pending` instead of `open` and see if you get the same error with `1` instead of `0`.

Comment: When I run `attributes_for` from the console I get: `{... :status=>:open, ...}`, but it does not build a project to associate. When I run `build(:project_item).attributes` I get: `{... "project_id"=>24,... "status"=>0, ...}`. If I change 'status' to `'pending'` or `:pending`, it does indeed give me the same error with 1 instead of 0. It looks like with Rails enums I wont be able to build forms in an intuitive way (with integer for value and string for the label), so it may be that enums are not going to make my life any easier at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm open to other solutions, but this is what I came up with as a workaround.

```
let(:project_attributes) { build(:project_item).attributes.merge(status: 'pending') }
it "creates a new ProjectItem" do
  expect {
    post :create, project_id: project.id, project_item: project_attributes
  }.to change(ProjectItem, :count).by(1)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Having to add a `.merge` across pre-existing factory calls is a nightmare.

All you need in your factory is
`status 'open'`