# Rails 4: Set enum field through FactoryGirl attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, factory-bot

I have a Model that has an enum as attribute.

```
class ApplicationLetter < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event

  validates :user, :event, presence: true

  enum status: {accepted: 1, rejected: 0, pending: 2}

end
```

As well as a factory that generates this model and sets a value for the enum

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :application_letter do
    motivation "motivation"
    user
    event
    status :accepted
  end
end
```

In a controller test I want to get valid attributes through the factory

```
let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.build(:application_letter).attributes }
```

and create a application with these attributes.

```
application = ApplicationLetter.create! valid_attributes
```

But I get the following error:

> ArgumentError:
>           '1' is not a valid status

Why is status interpreted as string? If I change the status in the factory I get the same error, but with the right corresponding number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factory Girl with enum and association](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606297/factory-girl-with-enum-and-association)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606297/factory-girl-with-enum-and-association, but there's no good answer there either. Might want to report this on [GitHub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) if it's still a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let(:valid_attributes) { FactoryGirl.build(:application_letter).attributes.merge(status: 'accepted') }
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. Unfortunately it does not help. The error remains exactly the same :/

Comment: Also, what type of data is stored in the status column in you db? It is an integer field, correct?

Comment: Yes it is an integer. Now it works with your updated answer and if I remove the entry in the factory. It looks a little bit hacky, but at least it works. Thank you very much :)

Comment: if it solved your issue could you accept the answer?

Comment: The solutions looks a little bit "hacky" for me. I am relatively new to Rails (and Ruby in general) but I think it would be nice to set the status in the factory directly like the other attributes. I already have upvoted your answer and it was indeed very helpful, but maybe their is a better solution which looks cleaner to me. If such a solution does not exists I will of course accept your answer :)

Answer (score 8):

you can do it more dynamically:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :application_letter do
    motivation "motivation"
    user
    event
    status { ApplicationLetter.statuses.values.sample }
  end
end
```

in this each time you will get different status

OR if wanna use static value you have to use integer, because `enum`s by default use integer values

Answer (score 3):

All you need in your factory is `status 'accepted'`.